# Value/offset in Tiff field/ IFD entry of TIFF image

Tags: image, tags, tiff, libtiff

I have an image with following IFD entries
01 00 00 03 00 00 00 01 09 A0 00 00
01 01 00 03 00 00 00 01 0C B0 00 00
.
.
.
01 0D 00 02 00 00 00 0E 00 00 DF A2
.
.
Here 
Tag ID - 010D (which is document name)
Tag type - 0002 (ASCII)
Count -0000000E  (14)
Offset address - 0000 DFA2

Similarly, what does last 4 bytes indicates (Value or offset) in IFD entry of 0100 (Image width) and 0101 (Image length)?

Comment: You will find this explained in the TIFF 6.0 specification. For the Width/Length cases, the value is a short (0x0003), and the count is 1 (2 * 1 < 4), thus the value is written "in-line". Your image is 0x9a0 * 0xcb0, or 2464 * 3248 pixels. For the DocumentName tag, the value is ASCII, the count is 14, and as this is > 4 bytes (1 * 14 > 4), the following value is an offset, and the real tag value can be found at that offset (0xdfa2).

Comment: Great .. Thanks @haraldK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [HaraldK’s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46535398/value-offset-in-tiff-field-ifd-entry-of-tiff-image#comment80077532_46535398), which seems to have solved OP’s problem:

You will find this explained in the TIFF 6.0 specification. For the Width/Length cases, the value is a short (0x0003), and the count is 1 (2 * 1 < 4), thus the value is written "in-line". Your image is 0x9a0 * 0xcb0, or 2464 * 3248 pixels. For the DocumentName tag, the value is ASCII, the count is 14, and as this is > 4 bytes (1 * 14 > 4), the following value is an offset, and the real tag value can be found at that offset (0xdfa2).